# Automatically create home directory on NFS after LDAP login

Tags: ldap, nfs, pam, autofs, pam-ldap

My  current situation is that I can successfully authenticate using `ldap` and `pam`, I also succeeded to use `pam_mkdir` to autocreate home directories in the `/home` filesystem.

What now I'm trying to achieve is to autocreate the same home directories but on an automounted nfs export. The automount works correctly and the `homes` root is correctly reachable. The aim is to avoid to create homes on the `nfs` manually.

I spent last two days lurking around, but I did not succeed to merge all the informations together.

The questions I still have:

- could `pam_mkdir` create directories over nfs?
- if the mounted `homes` path is not standard (e.g. homes are mounted to `/mnt/nfs/homes`), how `pam_mkdir` can know that? Using a `homeDirectory` LDAP attribute?
- Should I instead trigger the creation on the LDAP server after user creation?
- Am I overthinking an actually simpler problem?

Comment: I use mounting of the home directory on /etc/fstab.  I mount to /mnt/home.  I create a symlink /home -> /mnt/home.  The OS stays with its default and looks in /home for user profile.  As you know, it's really getting it from /mnt/home which is really server:/homedrive.  Having said all that, I cannot convince mine to make homedrive on the network either.  I'm fairly certain it's the local root not having permissions on the nfs server.  But I'm in the middle of a project and have not been able to research further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely that you're running into an NFS permissions issue. In a standard setup, NFS client machines are not trusted for root access on the NFS server; access by uid=0 is mapped to an unprivileged user (`nfsnobody` or similar). In order to create the home directory, `pam_mkdir` (which runs as root) would need to have permissions to the directory in which the user's homedir would be created (generally `/home/`), and when remapped to `nfsnobody`, this fails. You could disable this remapping option, but that's generally a bad idea; the better approach is to have a script that walks your LDAP directory and creates missing home directories on the NFS server directly.